# Signal for Entire Row Selection in QTableWidget

Tags: qt

Is there a signal for when an entire row in the QTableWidget has been selected by pressing the  buttons that are stacked on the left? I would like that to enable some functionality, but am not sure how?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of different options.  The most direct for what you've asked is to use the [QHeaderView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html) that's associated with the buttons:

```
// you could also use verticalHeader()
connect(tableWidget->horizontalHeader(), SIGNAL(sectionClicked(int)), ...);
```

Another option is to listen to the [selection model](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel):

```
connect(tableWidget->selectionModel(), SIGNAL(selectionChanged(const QItemSelection&, const QItemSelection&)), ...)
```

But, this option would require that you check the selection to see if only an entire row is selected, unless your [SelectionMode](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#SelectionMode-enum) prevents it from being otherwise.

Comment: Not sure why, but it didn't signal at all with `SIGNAL(selectionChanged(const QItemSelection&, const QItemSelection&))`. Instead, using `SIGNAL(currentChanged(const QModelIndex &, const QModelIndex &))` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
connect(tableWidget->selectionModel(), SIGNAL(currentChanged(const QModelIndex &, const QModelIndex &)), ...)
```

I got the idea from [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/44848-What-is-the-difference-between-selectionChanged-amp-currentChanged).